# jQuery How to affect Single element on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I'm still learning, this question might seem to be very simple to answer, but I still need to ask.

How do I need to change this script, so it will not display all the tooltips?

What is happening now is whenever I hover on `.pink-nose a` all the `.tooltip` are fading in at this same time

```
    $(function(){
        var pn = $('.pink-nose a')
        var tp = $('.pink-nose .tooltip')

        tp.css({'display':'none'})
        pn.mouseover(function(){
            tp.fadeIn()            
        })
    })
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `tp` in the handling function, you should start from `this` (the element that was moused over), and traverse to its related tooltip.  Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.pink-nose .tooltip').hide();

    $('.pink-nose a').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parents('.pink-nose:first').find('.tooltip').fadeIn();
    })
})
```

The exact traversal will depend on the structure of your markup, take a look at the [jQuery documentation for Traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) to figure out what will work best.

Comment: changed, ancestors to parents since ancestors is deprecated now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.pink-nose .tooltip').hide().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('a').mouseover(function() {
        $this.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe you will have some problems with reusing $this in the mouseover function. $this will not be bound the proper object.  if you add `var` infront of the $this it should work. Also, you need the function declaration within ght each method.

Comment: Good call with using `hide` instead of `css`

Comment: It isn't unless you declare it within the parent funciton.